# Python : Select text between angle brackets

Tags: python, pandas

I read a csv file and convert it to a pandas dataframe, with 2 text columns. In one column I have multiple rows of this form:

```
<suggested-actions-list text =""is this a test?"">suggested- 
action>Yes</suggested-action><suggested-action>No</suggested-action> 
</suggested-actions-list>"

<choice-list text=""some text""> <choice-option>option1</choice-option> 
<choice-option>option2</choice-option> <choice-option>option3</choice- 
option></choice-list>
```

I want to select the text between the angle brackets, in order to end up with something like this:

```
""is this a test?"" Yes No
""some text"" option1 option2 option3
```

Can someone give a hint? Thanks!

Comment: You can try beautifulsoup parser. You can also parse xml documents with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = """
<suggested-actions-list text =""is this a test?""><suggested-action>Yes</suggested-action><suggested-action>No</suggested-action></suggested-actions-list>

<choice-list text=""some text""> <choice-option>option1</choice-option><choice-option>option2</choice-option> <choice-option>option3</choice-option></choice-list>
"""

x = re.sub('<(?:.*?)("".*"")?>', r'\1 ', s)
x = re.sub('[ ]+', ' ', x)

print(x)
```

Output:

```
""is this a test?"" Yes No 

""some text"" option1 option2 option3
```

Note: I had to somewhat fix the original text, i.e. add `<` before the first "suggested-action" and remove `"` at the end of the first element. Let me know if that's not OK and we need to fix this in code as well

Answer (score 1):

1.Read this complete text in your code using readlines() which would give you a list of rows.

2.Using regex ,get text and other options in a list of lists.

3.Load list of lists in to a dataframe.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
df_list = []
data = open('filename.txt','r').readlines()
for row in data:
    m = re.search('=(.+?)>', text)
        text = m.group(1)
    row = re.sub('<.*?>','',row).split(' ')
    df_list.append([m,row[0],row[1],row[2])
data_df = pd.Dataframe(df_list)
```